# Error of auto image slideshow by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, image

I am using a code to run Auto Image slideshow with Javascript. It works quite well. But there is an error that after running a full lap, it will automatically scroll down and then roll back up.
Is there a way to fix this.

```js
var myIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementById("slide-banner").getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  myIndex++;
  if (myIndex > x.length) {
    myIndex = 1
  }
  x[myIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  setTimeout(carousel, 2500);
}
```

```css
#slide-banner {
  position: relative
}
```

```html
<div id='slide-banner'>
  <div class='mySlides'>
    <a href='#'><img src='/banner-1' style='width:100%' /></a>
  </div>
  <div class='mySlides'>
    <a href='#'><img src='/banner-2' style='width:100%' /></a>
  </div>
  <div class='mySlides'>
    <a href='#'><img src='/banner-3' style='width:100%' /></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: that is because the images on the page or not same size.

Comment: It automatically swims to the location where the final image should be...

Comment: it would be better if you also add the image files (by uploading them on imgur and adding link in the src(s) ) to exactly match your test scenario